# how to post a message in activemq topic using curl command?

Tags: java, curl, activemq-classic

How does one post a message in an ActiveMQ topic using `curl`? I tried:

```
curl -XPOST -d "body=message" http://admin:admin@localhost:8161/api/message?destination=queue://orders.input
```

but the response is unauthorized user 401.

Answer (score 5):

Per [the ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) both of the following worked for me:

```
curl -XPOST -u admin:admin -d "body=message" http://localhost:8161/api/message/orders.input?type=queue

curl -XPOST -d "body=message with alt syntax" http://admin:admin@localhost:8161/api/message?destination=queue://orders.input
```

Are you able to log into the web interface and view the queues using the credentials `admin/admin`? Try to view http://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp to confirm.